# RedHat Server duplicates eth0 on boot

Tags: networking, azure, redhat, virtual-machines, virtual-network

I have setup a *RedHat 9* VM on *Azure cloud* with **one** virtual NIC which the VM recognizes as `eth0`. However, I have noticed that after booting up or restarting, the VM creates a duplicate device `eth1` with the same IP address as `eth0`. `eth1` does not appear anywhere in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/*`
Trying to delete it using `ip link delete eth1` produces the error `RTNETLINK answers: Operation not supported`. Trying `iw dev eth1 del` produces the error `command failed: No such device (-19)`. Has anyone ever encountered this? How do I get rid of `eth1`?

Output of `ip addr show`

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:0d:3a:7e:38:97 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.208.58.25/24 brd 10.208.58.255 scope global noprefixroute eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::20d:3aff:fe7e:3897/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,SLAVE,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq master eth0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:0d:3a:7e:38:97 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enP56023p0s2
    altname enP56023s1
    inet 10.208.58.25/24 brd 10.208.58.255 scope global noprefixroute eth1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::1c5a:6948:4f3e:eb48/64 scope link tentative noprefixroute
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

**Updates**

Output of `nmcli connection show`

```
NAME                UUID                                  TYPE      DEVICE
System eth0         5fb06bd0-0bb0-7ffb-45f1-d6edd65f3e03  ethernet  eth0
Wired connection 1  89a97159-d783-33fb-a2a7-e6e4b82601d4  ethernet  eth1
eth0                7b956762-5a6d-4bc3-b568-54f7b82a5ed1  ethernet  --
```

**More updates**

Creating an `ifcfg-eth1` in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/` with the entries below seems to solve my problem:

```
DEVICE=eth1
ONBOOT=no
```

`eth1` is still present but at least it does not get assigned an IP address hence the affected service does not crash.

Comment: First, please don't post pictures of text; post the text itself, formatted as a code sample. That makes it easier to read (and otherwise interact with). Second, that appears to be the output of `ifconfig`, which isn't particularly useful these days. Please replace it with the output of `ip addr show`.

Comment: @larsks thanks. I've replaced image with `ip addr show` contents

Answer (score 0):

That looks like you have a bond interface configured on your system. You can confirm this by running `ip -d addr show`, which will show you additional interface configuration details. You should see that `eth0` is a bond interface; the output should include something like:

```
    bond mode 802.3ad miimon 140 ...
```

We already see that `eth1` is a member of the `eth0` bond from your existing output:

```
3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,SLAVE,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq master eth0 state UP group default qlen 1000
```

Specifically, the `master eth0` part. In the `-d` output, you should see:

```
    bond_slave state ACTIVE mii_status UP link_failure_count ...
```

---

The interface is probably configured via NetworkManager (`/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts` is mostly of historic interest); take a look at the toutput of `nmcli connection show`.

Comment: creating an ifcfg-eth1 with entries below seems to solve the IP address issue:

`DEVICE=eth1`
`ONBOOT=no`